# Angularjs - Show True/False as Yes/No

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a simple way to show a true/false value as yes/no?

I am retrieving from the Database a JSON that contains :

> [Object, Object, "WithCertification": true]

This is the html:

> With Certification **{{elem.WithCertification}}**

Is displaying this:

**With Certification true**

I want it to display this:

**With Certification yes**

Is there a way without having to go to the controller to change the true/false to yes/no?

Anyhow I need to change it, any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can have [ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) inside [Angular Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression), so just do this:

```
With Certification {{elem.WithCertification?'yes':'no'}}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
{{elem.WithCertification == true ? "Yes" : "No"}}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use either a filter or a ternary operator. The filter would probably be better from what i've read ternary operators are frowned upon.

```
app.filter('YesNo', function(){
        return function(text){
          return text ? "Yes" : "No";
        }
      })
```

The code is fairly simple set your app.filter, give it a name, inside pass an anon function, returning a function that takes your true,false as a param, then return the text and determine if true or false, if true return yes, otherwise no.

Alternatively do it inside the tag.

```
<td>{{item.value ? "Yes":"No"}}</td>
```

You can see this working here http://plnkr.co/edit/altgrjKhXHACmczOvGFw

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to create a custom filter, as it is best to put as less logic in the view as possible. Below is a sample code showing you how to achieve this.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.filter('yesOrNo', function() {
return function(input) {
  return input === 'true' ? 'yes' : 'no' ;
};
})
```

In html, you would just do:-

```
With Certification {{elem.WithCertification | yesOrNo}}
```

Comment: Why the downvote?? If the downvote is because I suggested creating a filter, see my reply to Remco's answer. I stand by my statement that creating a filter is the best option here. True, you may have to write 6 extra lines of code, but it's worth the effort.

Comment: First of all: a filter for something like this is an overkill, specially since the only thing that you are doing is a ternary operator, if you were using extra logic that would make the angular expression difficult to read, or using javascript code that you can 't have inside the angular expression that would be another story and having a $filter would be the way to go. Second: in the view you are using a filer called: 'yesOrNo', but the filter that you have defined is called 'myFilter'.

Comment: Sorry, my bad!! It was a typo, edited it. But regarding filter being an overkill, I disagree. Angularjs itself has built-in filters like lowercase, uppercase which are just there for converting the case.

Comment: Then at least you should have he 'yes'-'no' as parameters, the filters that you are mentioning are not comparable with this.

Comment: I will remove my downvote now that you fixed the name of the filter.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a one time case, I agree with [Joseps answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26162527/1154610). Use:

```
With Certification {{elem.WithCertification?'yes':'no'}}
```

However, if you intend to use this more often, I would recommend using a filter. A very similar case is explained in [the AngularJS tutorial step 9](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09)

Comment: It reminded me that this is the exact same case as in the tutorial. It might be useful

Comment: Yes, why not. If the same logic is used more than 2-3 places, it is best to create a filter. You never know when requirement changes (like treating undefined as a maybe, however absurd it may sound), and imagine changing this logic in all the places where it is used.

Comment: In my opinion a filter for something like this is an overkill, specially since the only thing that we are doing is a ternary operator, if we were using extra logic that would make the angular expression difficult to read, or using javascript code that you can't have inside the angular expression that would be another story and having a $filter would be the way to go... But in this case a $filter is an overkill.