# AngularJS string replace on template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why this return a blank string on my template?

```
{{ selectedVehicle.air_conditioning.replace(true, "Yes") }}
```

Comment: Is this all code with you?

Comment: first check the value of `selectedVehicle.air_conditioning`, and I don´t think you are using the replace function correctly, try putting the `true` value in quotes like `'true'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.replace` method can't be applied on Boolean variable, it works on string only.
That's why you need to convert it to string then apply replace.

```
{{ selectedVehicle.air_conditioning.toString().replace(true, "Yes") }}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/13240/)

Hope this could help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Okay, if I get it:

- air_conditioning is a boolean ?
- you want to print yes when air_conditioning is true ?

you can just use ternary syntax like this:

```
{{ selectedVehicle.air_conditioning ? "Yes" : "No }}
```

Answer (score 0):

With out more info it is hard to give full help.  please update your post with example code, controller etc.

But that said try and have to look at this:

[How to display Yes/No instead of True/False in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611455/how-to-display-yes-no-instead-of-true-false-in-angularjs)