# Showing 'Yes' or 'No' depending of a boolean value with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, filter

I got this in my .html file :

```
<tr ng-repeat="collab in collabs">
    <td>{{collab.firstname}}</td>
    <td>{{collab.lastname}}</td>
    <td>{{collab.ext}}</td>
</tr>
```

`collab.ext` is a boolean value, and I want to show **Yes** when it is `true`, and **No** when it is `false`.

Does Angular provide something for this? :-)

Comment: Just use plain js expression -  [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) `{{collab.ext ? 'Yes' :'No'}}`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611455/how-to-display-yes-no-instead-of-true-false-in-angularjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ternary operator `if ? then : else` did the job great:

```
<tr ng-repeat="collab in collabs">
    <td>{{collab.firstname}}</td>
    <td>{{collab.lastname}}</td>
    <td>{{collab.ext ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make attempted to use "ng-if" ?

```
<div ng-if = "Variable == 5">
   <!- we do whatever we want ->
</div>
<div ng-if = 'variable! = 5 ">
   <!- we do whatever we want ->
</div>
```